# In hibernate search Integer value when indexed appears to be stored as characters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-search

I have a base class with

```
@Field
protected Integer group;
```

on hibernate 5.6.0.Final

I set my objects value to values 0 or 1. But when I observe the index using luke it always shows 4 stored rows as `h, p, x ,`

---

My tests work fine actually, when I add a MustJunction with range query on one of the group I get properly filtered results back. Maybe I am interpreting luke wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search stores numeric values as numeric fields in Lucene, by default. Which means that even if the value was stored in the index as is, you wouldn't have the "0" string or the "1" string in your index, but some binary value.

But even with that in mind, you're probably surprised to see different binary encoding for identical source values. It's an optimization: remember you're looking at the content of an inverted index, whose purpose isn't to look up values for a given document but to find documents matching a particular value.

If you're interested in how numeric indexing works in Lucene, you can have a look at the [IntField javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/index.html?overview-summary.html). But since you queries work, it would really only be out of curiosity :)